# Border-color with img

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a border with an image in shape of triangle ?

At the moment I am creating my triangle like this :

```
.triangle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 51px;
  width: 103px;



 &:after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border: inset 52px;
      border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
      border-top-style: solid;
     }
}
```

To make is red for example I do `border-color: #ae1800 transparent transparent transparent;`
but how would I be able to replace the color by a background-image ?

Thank you for answering.

Comment: Can you maybe post an example image, how it should look like? I don't get it. And maybe a codepen with your already tried example.

Comment: This basically create a triangle shape, height 51px width 103px. The color is defined by border-color, the transparent right bottom left is basically what makes it triangle

Comment: Yes like that: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrELa/. But I really don't get, why you want to use an image in the border? just place a background image...?

Comment: Instead of the gray color I would want to put texture that I repeat in it. As a "background" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to create just an image with the border in something like photoshop and then make it with a transparent background outside of the triangle. Instead of using css to show it use JS instead.

I hope this helps!